# starting debugger cdbengine for abi "x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit" hangs in qtcreator

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, qt-creator, windbg

I added the x64 cdb from `Windows Kits 10` to debugger settings in the `MSVC 2015 64bit` Kit in `qtcreator 4.1.0` on latest Windows 10.

But when I run the debugger for my application, the debugger seems to start really slowly. Even a first run of hello world takes 3 minutes to start and finish, same with my own applications. After the first time debugging start, sometimes it is a bit faster (less than 1 min) but still not as fast as on linux, which almost instantly shows up and finishes running the program.

It shows:

```
starting debugger cdbengine for abi "x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit"
```

for a long time.

Any idea on how to fix this slow launching ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Szpaqn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322909/10415695) (I can't comment yet):

Instead of deleting the whole config directory, it's sufficient to just delete:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\debuggers.xml
```

After that and restarting QtCreator, I had to re-select the CDB as Debugger for the current Kit in `Tools -> Options -> Kits`.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to delete QtCreator files from

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\QtProject.
```

Comment: Yes this solution does fix the problem.  However it seems rather drastic in deleting all those files.  It would be nice if someone figured out exactly which files to delete in that directory rather than deleting everything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using Qt Creator 4.6.0 with CDB and a MSVC 2013 64-bit kit. I found that it correlated with times that my internet connection was slow. In Qt Creator, I went to Tools > Options > Debugger > CDB Paths and deleted the line pointing to the Microsoft symbol server:[image]

After deleting that line, my debugger started quickly again.

Comment: I can confirm this.